# Unable to Run Flask on Twisted web server, WSGI application error

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, twisted, twisted.web

I'm new to flask. I want to deploy my flask application on prod, so for that I want to use Twisted web server (on windows). 
Below is my proj structure and I'm using Blueprints:
[image]

my run.py file is as below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from ProjName import app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

command I'm trying is :

```
twistd web --wsgi run.app
```

In top most **init**.py I'm just doing :

```
app = Flask(__name__)
```

And rest code is related to registering blueprints.

What changes do I need to make in my files so as to run on twisted web? Or do I need to completely restructure my code?

PS: I know my question may not be clear. I've referred some links but it is just confusing me. Appreciate your help!

Comment: What happened?  What did you expect to happen that's different?

Comment: i want to run this flask application. but getting error 'no such wsgi application'

Answer (score 5):

You haven't put the root of your source tree into Python's import path so the module name "run" can't be resolved.  Fix it by setting PYTHONPATH (for example):

```
export PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:${PWD}
twistd web --wsgi run.app
```

Comment: I've set this PYTHONPATH. But still getting same error.

Comment: You can run `python -v $(type -p twistd) web --wsgi run.app` to get import search path debug information which may help you narrow the problem down further.

Comment: this is also valid and can be useful  on Windows where one can write something like `set PYTHONPATH=F:\Appl\myapp\flask;`